# How to get Display Size [HAXE FLIXEL]

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I was just wondering how I could get the size of the display in HaxeFlixel (usually 1920,1080/1280,720). This is not to be confused with the window size.

Answer (score 2):

You could use https://api.openfl.org/openfl/system/Capabilities.html#screenResolutionX / https://api.openfl.org/openfl/system/Capabilities.html#screenResolutionY to obtain resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see this in your Main.hx file. It should look something like this:

```java
class Main extends Sprite {
    public function new() {
        super();
        addChild(new FlxGame(1920, 1080, GameState, true));
    }
}
```